# Speed Difference between accessing Object Attribute / List Access?

Tags: python, performance, processing-efficiency

I'm performing numerical integration over a "for" loop (on the scale of 10^3 loops) and I would like to make it so that it runs as fast as possible. In each time loop the properties of several physical objects (neurons) are used to calculate the derivatives.

In my implementation, these neurons are python instances of a class. The only reason I'm using a class is to store certain changeable properties of the neuron in its own instance.

Would it be faster to store these properties in lists instead, such that each neuron is associated with a list instead of a class instance?

```
    for t in time_array:
            for node in neuron_dict:

                    p_derivative = find_p_derivative(node,neuron_dict[node].p_initial, neuron_dict[node].q_initial, neuron_dict[node].n_initial)
                    q_derivative = find_q_derivative(node,neuron_dict[node].p_initial, neuron_dict[node].q_initial, neuron_dict[node].n_initial)
                    n_derivative = find_n_derivative(node,neuron_dict[node].p_initial, neuron_dict[node].q_initial, neuron_dict[node].n_initial)

                    neuron_dict[node].p = neuron_dict[node].p_initial + (t_step * p_derivative)
                    neuron_dict[node].q = neuron_dict[node].q_initial + (t_step * q_derivative)
                    neuron_dict[node].n = neuron_dict[node].n_initial + (t_step * n_derivative)
```

Comment: It would probably be faster as a list (I assume, I don't know how your full code looks like), but it's really easy to just check it yourself

Comment: It _may_ be marginally faster, once the code is running, to have those properties in a dictionary instead of a class (and almost certainly less overhead when you start the program up). However, have you explored numpy/scipy here? It may require effort to reformulate the problem into arrays but I'm not sure we see enough of what you're trying to solve, ultimately, to be able to help

Comment: @OferSadan Thank you, I timed and compared a simpler version of the two implementations and the class one was faster by a fraction of about 1/10. The for loop used for integration in my code takes up most (>99%) of the execution time, so that was the only part I thought worth sharing.

Comment: @frances_farmer that's interesting, and if that's the case I agree that you should probably use `numpy`, it tends to save a lot on loops